# Область видимости пары (pair). Пара, объявленная в структуре, не видна в другом классе

Tags: c++

Суть задачи: имеется файл header, внутри объявлена структура и класс. В структуре объявлена пара, только вот она не видна в классе (когда же просто добавляю любое поле, оно видно в классе).

Пример кода:

```
struct MyStr
{
    pair<int, int> p;
} s;

class Class
{
    int val;
    Class()
    {
        s.p.first = 2;
    }
};

void main()
{
    getchar();
}
```

Упс, кажется, разобрался. Просто забыл обращаться через структуру. =)

Comment: Дайте код, без него ничего не понятно. Желательно упростить его до максимально простого примера.

Comment: О, вот видите.

Comment: @TheStigger1, По возможности публикуйте ответы на форуме, они могут помочь многим в будущем.